Unable to write to the Defined Name variable using jxls 3.0
I have below Defined Name variable in excel template.
Name     Value                                      RefersTo     Scope                            
period   Period: ${data.startDate}-${data.endDate}  =globalVariables!$B$9:$B$10                WorkBook

I am using the JxlsPoiTemplateFillerBuilder to write the map data to workbook.
This is the code to create report.
URL templateUrl = new URL("file://" + viewTemplatePath);
byte[] transformedBytes = JxlsPoiTemplateFillerBuilder.newInstance().withTemplate(templateUrl)
    .buildAndFill(map);
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new ByteArrayInputStream(transformedBytes));

I am creating the map as below:
Class MyDate {
     String startDate;
     String endDate;
}

MyDate myDate = new Date("01/03/2024", "02/03/2024");
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.add("data", myDate);


Currently the cell where Define name has placed is getting populated with 0.
I am expecting to get Period: 01/03/2024 - 02/03/2024 value at the defined cell.
